# Linked list insertion and reverse output

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

I have this code which I am working on add some strings a a linked list to have the list reversed. But I am getting a segment fault error.

`segmentation fault: 11` is what I see on the complier.

There might be memory allocation issues involved but that is not important at this time.

There is also a warning of character constant too long for its type. I am not sure what that means.

How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct Node { 
    char *data[100]; 
    struct Node *next; 
}; 

static void reverse(struct Node **head_ref) { 
    struct Node *prev = NULL; 
    struct Node *current = *head_ref; 
    struct Node *next = NULL; 
    while (current != NULL) { 
        // Store next 
        next = current->next; 

        // Reverse current node's pointer 
        current->next = prev; 

        // Move pointers one position ahead. 
        prev = current; 
        current = next; 
    } 
    *head_ref = prev; 
} 

void push(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data) { 
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    new_node->data = new_data; 
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); 
    (*head_ref) = new_node; 
} 

void printList(struct Node *head) { 
    struct Node *temp = head; 
    while (temp != NULL) { 
        printf("%s ", temp->data); 
        temp = temp->next; 
    }
}

int main() { 
    /* Start with the empty list */
    struct Node *head = NULL; 

    push(&head, "hi"); 
    push(&head, "hello");
    push(&head, "mello"); 

    printf("Given linked list\n"); 
    printList(head); 
    reverse(&head); 
    printf("\nReversed Linked list \n"); 
    printList(head); 
    getchar(); 
}
```

Comment: "There is also a warning of character constant too long for its type". Please show the exact warnings. Also FYI, "segmentation fault" is not from the compiler it is from your running program.

Comment: @kaylum `character constant too long for its type` That was the warning. Thank you for you correction.

Comment: A few errors: `char * data[100]` should probably be `char data[100]` or `char * data`. Next: `char new_data` should be `char *new_data`. Next: `new_node->data = new_data` should be either `strcpy(new_node->data, new_data)` or `new_node->data = strdup(new_data)`

Comment: I also suggest using `const char *` instead of `char *`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your push function you seem to be passing a `char` when you mean to pass a `char *`.

Furthermore, you are assigning `new_data` to an array in that same function.

If you change your `data` variable to type `char *` only, you can make this assignation. This will mean you will need to allocate the necessary memory based on the size of each string before but as you mentioned this is not important now.

Here is the code with those 2 changes, and tested to be working;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Node {
    char * data;
    struct Node* next;
};


static void reverse(struct Node** head_ref)
{
    struct Node* prev = NULL;
    struct Node* current = *head_ref;
    struct Node* next = NULL;
    while (current != NULL) {
        // Store next
        next = current->next;

        // Reverse current node's pointer
        current->next = prev;

        // Move pointers one position ahead.
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head_ref = prev;
}


void push(struct Node** head_ref, char * new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}


void printList(struct Node* head)
{
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


int main(){
    /* Start with the empty list */
    struct Node* head = NULL;

    push(&head, "hi");
    push(&head, "hello");
    push(&head, "mello");


    printf("Given linked list\n");
    printList(head);
    reverse(&head);
    printf("\nReversed Linked list \n");
    printList(head);
    getchar();
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The posted code does not compile!

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

The following shows how to compile the code using `gcc` and the results.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 

untitled1.c: In function ‘push’:

untitled1.c:29:20: error: assignment to expression with array type
     new_node->data = new_data;
                    ^

untitled1.c: In function ‘printList’:

untitled1.c:37:18: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%s ", temp->data);
                 ~^    ~~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled1.c:46:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘push’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     push(&head, "hi");
                 ^~~~

untitled1.c:27:6: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void push(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data) {
      ^~~~

untitled1.c:47:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘push’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     push(&head, "hello");
                 ^~~~~~~

untitled1.c:27:6: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void push(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data) {
      ^~~~

untitled1.c:48:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘push’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     push(&head, "mello");
                 ^~~~~~~

untitled1.c:27:6: note: expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void push(struct Node **head_ref, char new_data) {
      ^~~~

Compilation failed.
```